# Sort numbers from a loop

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code

```
 for (short i = 100; i >= 1; i--) 
   {OutputFormattedXmlElement("test", i.ToString());}
```

i am using the "test" to populate a dropdownlist

```
 <select id="list><xsl:apply-templates select="/sales/test">...
```

My problem is that in the dropdownlist it shows the 1 as the default (correct) but it is at the bottom of the list and i want it at the top.

Where do i have to make a change? Is there any other way except javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean 1 then 100,99,98 .... then output 1 first and then run the loop with `i > 1` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping from 100 down to 1, meaning that 100 is the first item and 1 is the last. It would seem to me that reversing the loop might give you better results.

Comment: I tried that and it has 100 as a default which is something that i dont want.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the selected item, or are you relying on a default? If it's the latter, you're out of luck.

Comment: hmm on default... Here you will see exactly what i mean http://shots.gr/up/d4234d085971f1e0a20f327a0b990b63.png

Comment: Reverse for loop order than change value for dropdown using controlName.SelectedValue = 1?

Comment: can you give an example please

Comment: Can you give us the body of the OutputFormattedXmlElement method?

Comment: The problem was in different block of code but part of the solution was to reverse the loop. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just reverse your `for` loop?

```
for (short i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
   {OutputFormattedXmlElement("test", i.ToString());}
```

Comment: I tried that and it has 100 as a default which is something that i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, is it valid to simply flip the for loop?

```
for (short i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    ...
```

Comment: I tried that and it has 100 as a default which is something that i dont want.